# What does broad, broader and broadly mean?

Tags: grammar

When I say they are broadly known as this, they are broadly classified into two, A broad reason, A broad feature, A broad category, A broader reason, A broader category. What does broad broadly and broader mean?

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: In general and without considering minor details, big, wide but i dont think these meanings go well in the above context

Comment: First off, are the words adjectives or adverbs?

Comment: I'm glad I've been of some help; and I look forward to more questions from you. Could I ask you, please, when writing on this site to take special care to write *can't*  and *for example, right now* instead of *cant, eg rn.* Text-spelling makes it difficult for some students to practice good English, and in any case it annoys many of the people who take the trouble to reply.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sir. I will keep that in mind for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, Apples are categorized as Cookers and Eaters (dessert). There is considerable overlap; Blenheims for instance are dual purpose. And this categorization leaves out cider apples, crab apples, and ornamental apple trees.

More broadly speaking, apples, pears and quinces are distinguished from other top fruit such as cherries and plums; all may be referred to more broadly as orchard fruit to distinguish them from strawberries.

If I want to discuss fruit-growing on a broader scale in the context of all land use, I will lose even more detail and not mention separate fruits at all, let alone individual varieties. I may simply sat that 2000 hectares are down to fruit, 5000 to cereal crops, 6000 hectares of upland grazing to sheep.

If the aim is to discuss the self sufficiency in agriculture it would be silly to start mentioning each cow by name and what she had for breakfast; I must talk broadly about improvements in silage, productivity versus sustainability, imports and exports.

Broader implies more generalization. There is inevitably loss of detail, but this may give a clearer overall picture of a situation, or trend, or policy.  Sometimes this is referred to a 'painting with a broader brush.'

Comment: Understood what Broadly classified means. And the other ones pls kindly explain that too pls. broadly known as, broad features, broader reasons, broad reasons?

Comment: Sometimes I have seen that we say broad category but inside of that there arent any varieties. If it is so then how is it general and not specific?

Comment: Could you give an example of that.

Comment: I cant think of a specific eg rn but there are many instances where we say there are x types of something but we see that those types cant be further divided. Then how are they broad?

Comment: And if I say Y is suppose broadly known as something. Here the question of generalisation doesnt arise. So what does broadly here mean?

Comment: Rrrrhh, I'm not sure I can help you. There is nothing in this world which cannot be reconsidered in greater detail; or discussed more generally in softer focus. Shields and swords are more broadly called armour. Men and armour are more broadly, soldiers/ troops. Troops and fortification is, more broadly, defense.

Comment: Got it. So it doesnt only  include not considering minor details but also not considering specific instances where it may have been called by some other name, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The sub-category might be pens pencils and paper; but when it is discussed more broadly they become 'stationery' or 'writing materials.' And more broadly still they may be called 'equipment.'

Comment: I understood what you meant sir by the above example.But when I say not the subcategories but a single thing, suppose Y is broadly known as That. Here in broad sense it is that Y is generally known as that and maybe on specific purposes that particular thing is known by some other name but we aren't concerned with that,right?And Also when i say there are 2 broad categories but see that it can't be divided further then it means that these are the two basic categories and we are not even concerned whether there are varieties inside or outside them or not?

Comment: Now, that is a different use of 'broader.' Again I shall work from an example. Take *a birthday cake;* you seem to be saying that all there is to be said about the birthday cake is "That is a lovely birthday cake, I am enjoying the birthday cake, Isn't it nice." If you want to broaden out the discussion, you must find different points of view. For this it is useful to look at Aristotle's categories. Then you can talk about the taste, texture, what number of years, The broader perspective can include the people involved in baking and celebrating; how it compares with last year's.

Comment: And there is one more step. The ethical and social perspective. This is where you start talking about clothing and the discussion broadens from style, to include sweat shops, fake fur, sustainability, disposal. To add to your list of *categories* you will have to make your own list of *perspectives.* This will reflect your interests. Is *community* important to you? or *aesthetics* ?

Comment: If I say two broad personality traits are extraversion and agreeableness and two narrow personality traits are toughmindedness and optimism. What does broad and narrow here mean?